# Is there a way to sort within DistinguishedName

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to get a list of users and Id like to sort based on the last OU= in DistinguishedName. The syntax I'm using isn't quite right and I need some pointers. Thank You

```
get-aduser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties * | where {($_.EmployeeNumber -eq $null) -and ($_.PrimaryGroup -eq 'CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=OURDOMAIN,DC=net')} | FT SamAccountName,Name,EmployeeNumber,DistinguishedName,Created | export-csv Users.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for the [`msDS-parentdistname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adls/85d11f99-0988-4996-97fb-bfa95e0159b2) attribute in AD. It's a relatively new attribute, so it's possible it's not available on the version of Windows Server that you're running in your environment. But you can see if it's there.

It's a constructed attribute, which means it's calculated at the time it's asked for. But that also means you have to explicitly ask for it (you can't use `-Properties *`).

The use [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6) to sort your list.

```
get-aduser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties SamAccountName,Name,EmployeeNumber,DistinguishedName,Created,msDS-parentdistname | where {($_.EmployeeNumber -eq $null) -and ($_.PrimaryGroup -eq 'CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=OURDOMAIN,DC=net')} | Sort-Object msDS-parentdistname | FT SamAccountName,Name,EmployeeNumber,DistinguishedName,Created,msDS-parentdistname | export-csv Users.csv
```